# Viewport display girid floor, axis for y and x, and color have gone weird, how do I put it back to default

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

need suggestions on how I could fix this. 3.1 was just fine but when I installed 3.2 it just shows this in the 3d viewport

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Paradox try Arc Blend add-on automatically you can reset the view theme:

https://github.com/stunmuffin/Arc_Blend

If you want to change manuel,

Go to Viewport Shading,

Make your choise "Studio" is default,

Select Background "Theme",

[image]

And maybe your clip end value is too low.

[image]

You have to update your clip end.
[image]

Comment: It seems to have no effect

Comment: Hey @Paradox look again. Go to "N" Panel use keyboard "N" Go to View Panel and clip end you have to change this value bigger numbers. I hope this will works.